# Назначение пользовательского имени для кастомной функции внутри pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, lambda

Собираю данные в сводной таблице, нужно вывести процентили. Стандартная функция из нумпая не работает внутри, поэтому создаю лямбда функцию вот в таком виде:

```
service_usage = costs.pivot_table(index=['disconnected_status'], values=['MonthlyCharges', 'TotalCharges'], 
                aggfunc={'MonthlyCharges': 
                         [np.mean, np.var, np.std, lambda x: np.percentile(x, 25), lambda x: np.percentile(x, 75)], 
                         'TotalCharges': 
                         [np.mean,np.var, np.std, lambda x: np.percentile(x, 50), lambda x: np.percentile(x, 75)]})
```

На выходе получаются вот такие заголовки:

```
MonthlyCharges  TotalCharges
<lambda_0>  <lambda_1>  mean    std     var     <lambda_0>  <lambda_1>  mean    std     var
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как назначать имена для своих функций, чтоб на выходе не иметь <lambda_0>, а получить, например, "25%".

Comment: Попробуйте создать не как лямбды, а обычную функции, и потом перезаписать у нее свойство `__name__`, например `func.__name__ = "25%"`, после этого уже передавать в `pivot_table`.

Comment: @insolor, этот комментарий тянет на полноценный ответ. Может оформите как ответ? :)

Comment: @MaxU, я не проверял, работает ли это на numpy, просто предположил, что отображаемое имя зависит от этого свойства. Если автор вопроса подтвердит, что это ему помогло, тогда думаю оформить ответом.

Comment: @insolor, я тоже не проверял, но на 95% уверен, что это должно сработать

Comment: Спасибо, если переписывать свойство, то это работает, просто идея была именно в том, чтоб все внутри завернуть, а не выносить за пределы. Я все уже перегуглил, но внутри pivot_table только лямбды и работают.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

За отображаемое имя отвечает поле `__name__` объекта:

```
import numpy as np 
print(np.mean.__name__)  # Вывод: mean
print((lambda: 1).__name__)  # Вывод: <lambda>
```

Можно вынести лямбды в отдельные функции, перезаписать поле `__name__`, потом передать функции в `pivot_table`:

```
def percentile25(x):
    return np.percentile(x, 25)


percentile25.__name__ = "25%"


def percentile50(x):
    return np.percentile(x, 50)


percentile50.__name__ = "50%"


def percentile75(x):
    return np.percentile(x, 75)


percentile75.__name__ = "75%"


service_usage = costs.pivot_table(index=['disconnected_status'], values=['MonthlyCharges', 'TotalCharges'], 
                aggfunc={'MonthlyCharges': 
                         [np.mean, np.var, np.std, percentile25, percentile75], 
                         'TotalCharges': 
                         [np.mean, np.var, np.std, percentile50, percentile75]})
```

Если вынос в отдельные функции вас не подходит, сделайте функцию, которая будет перезаписывать это поле у лямбды (так даже удобнее, я думаю):

```
def set_name(callable, name):
    callable.__name__ = name
    return callable


service_usage = costs.pivot_table(index=['disconnected_status'], values=['MonthlyCharges', 'TotalCharges'], 
                    aggfunc={'MonthlyCharges': 
                            [np.mean, np.var, np.std,
                                set_name(lambda x: np.percentile(x, 25), "25%"),
                                set_name(lambda x: np.percentile(x, 75), "75%")], 
                            'TotalCharges': 
                            [np.mean, np.var, np.std,
                                set_name(lambda x: np.percentile(x, 50), "50%"),
                                set_name(lambda x: np.percentile(x, 75), "75%")]})
```

Comment: Ух ты, очень круто получилось, огромное спасибо!